# Which of the following can be used to open a file (t3.txt) located in different location (d:\Documents) for reading?

Tags: python, directory

a) `with open(“t3.txt”, “r”) as f:`

b) `with open(“Documents\t3.txt”, “r”) as f:`

c) `with open(“d:\\Documents\\t3.txt”, “r”) as f:`

d) any of the above

is anyone willing to explain how to know which will allow me to open the file that is located at a different location? I tried and c) works.

Comment: Why not simply try all three of the first and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
with open(“t3.txt”, “r”) as f:
```

and this

```
with open(“Documents\t3.txt”, “r”) as f:
```

use relative paths, whilst

```
with open(“d:\Documents\t3.txt”, “r”) as f:
```

does use absolute path, therfore first and second will work if you are in certain working directory (`d:\Documents` and `d:\` respectively) whilst third works independently from current working directory.